# Nested partial types in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, graphql

I'm trying to type partial objects from GraphQL queries. In particular, I'm having trouble with an object similar to as follows ...

```
// Typescript types

interface Foo {
  bar: Bar
}

interface Bar {
  a: number,
  b: number
}

// GrapQL query

foo {
  bar {
    a
    // Note missing 'b' property
  }
}
```

When I pcome to type this response I can use `Pick` on the `Bar` property, but this then violates `Foo`s declaration. I could create an entire new type but in my actual axample both `Foo` and `Bar` are complex objects - is there an easier way to type the result? How do people normally type GraphQL results?

Comment: asking for one field doesn't mean 2nd doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend to use some existing package that can generate that types for you. eg [gql code generator](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/)

otherwise easy way to avoid this type is to create partial types within whole object tree

```
interface Foo {
    bar: Bar;
}

interface Bar {
    a: number;
    b: number;
}

type partial<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends object ? partial<T[K]> : T[K] 
}

const partialFoo: partial<Foo> = {
    bar: {
        a: 1
    }
}
```